# Redux-form 6.0.0 access error outside Field component

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

In Redux-form v5 I was able to access to the "inline" errors (async validation) from anywhere in the decorated form, like so:

```
const fields = [
  'email'
]

// inside the decorated form
const { email } = this.props.fields

console.log(email.error) // 'the validation error of the 'email' field
```

How can I achieve the same thing using Redux-form 6.0.0+ ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are wanting to display the error next to the input, then it should be handled in the `component` that you pass to `Field`. If you want to display all the errors together, like at the bottom of the form by the submit button, you could use the new [`Fields` component](http://redux-form.com/6.0.0-rc.5/docs/api/Fields.md/) like so:

```
const fieldNames = [
  'email',
  'password'
]

const renderAllErrors = fields => (
  <ul>
    {Object.keys(fields).map(key => {
      const { meta: { touched, error } } = fields[ key ]
      return touched && error ? <li key={key}>{key}: {error}</li> : undefined
    })}
  </ul>
)

...

<Fields names={fieldNames} component={renderAllErrors}/>
```

Comment: When I loop over the fields, one of the props is the names array.  From reading the documentation(http://redux-form.com/6.0.2/docs/api/Fields.md/#props) I thought it wouldn't be added as a prop.  When I run the code above I get - Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'touched' of undefined(…)

Comment: Just an FYI for anyone using this in the future. If you want to conditionally show the error-list remember to do the check within you `renderAllErrors` method. Wrapping `Fields` in a custom component and doing the check there can result in that the `Fields`-component unmounts and unregisters all `fieldNames`.

Comment: @DomHede I experienced the same. `fields` also contains the `names` property of Forms. You can filter it by `{Object.keys(fields).filter(x => x.name =! "names").map(key ...`

Answer (score 2):

The solution I found is to use the `error` prop (http://redux-form.com/6.0.0-rc.4/docs/api/Props.md/#-error-any-).
From my `asyncValidate` function I fill the returned `error._error` object with my fields errors. I can then access it from the decorated form using 
`const { error } = this.props`.

If anyone has a better solution...

Edit: don't do this. Use the valid answer (`Fields` component).

Comment: Hi Erik, actually I'm not happy with that solution cause I can't know if the form field has been `touched` or not. So it displays every errors of every fields. Still looking for a proper way to replicate the behaviour of v5. (thanks for your amazing work on this project btw).

Comment: How about accessing the syncErrors object?