# Is there a way to get access to redux-form errors from inside the Container with reduxForm V7?

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

Previously, in Redux-Form V5, I was accessing errors as `email.error` and `password.error` from inside the render function.

In V7, my CSS is giving me grief to do it this way:

```
const renderInput = (field) => {
    const { meta: { touched, error } } = field

    return (
        <div>
            <input type={field.type} placeholder={field.placeholder} {...field.input} />
            <div className="inputErrorText">
                {touched ? error : ''} // this doesnt work due to my CSS
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

// ...inside the Container:

<div className="ui left icon input">
    <i className="user icon"></i>
    <Field
        name="email"
        component={renderInput}
        type="text"
        placeholder="Enter your Email"
    />
</div>

// Below is the old way I was doing it
{/*email.touched && email.error && <div className="inputErrorText">{email.error}</div>*/}
```

If I render the errors via `renderInput()`, the CSS gets mangled due to what looks like some position relative+absolute reasons, so I need the errors to render below that last div at the bottom of my code above.

How can I deal with rendering the field errors outside `renderInput()` and/or elsewhere in the `<form>`. I think my question centers around the `field` input parameter of `renderInput()`. How to access it inside the Container? Is it available on `this.props` anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

I just got it working. I found this source: [Redux-form 6.0.0 access error outside Field component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39035734/redux-form-6-0-0-access-error-outside-field-component?rq=1) which illustrates a way to use the `Fields` component of redux-form V6 & 7.

I wasn't able to get it working as shown there. I'm not entirely sure at this point, but it was throwing all kinds of "`cannot read property touched of undefined`". I tried many combinations of if (!fields) return else destructure, and about 20 different combinations and I just couldn't get it to iterate through using `Object.keys()`. I was able to console log easily `fields.email.input` and see everything, but as soon as I started digging into `meta`, it started throwing undefined even while it was logging the values sometimes. The weird thing is `untouched` was always `false` not `undefined`, so it was fairly infuriating, but I digress.

Another person may have more luck with that above solution. `Fields` is definitely what a person wants to use to gain control over errors in Redux-form V6-7.

I did however, get it to work like this:

```
import { reduxForm, Field, Fields } from 'redux-form'

const fieldNames = [
    'email',
    'password'
]

const renderInput = (field) => {
    return (
        <input type={field.type} placeholder={field.placeholder} {...field.input} />
    )
}

// inside the Container (class methods)
renderEmailError({ email }) {
    const { touched, error } = email.meta
    if (touched && error) return <div className="inputErrorText">{error}</div>
    return null
}

renderPasswordError({ password }) {
    const { touched, error } = password.meta
    if (touched && error) return <div className="inputErrorText">{error}</div>
    return null
}

// Inside render function
<div className="field">
    <div className="ui left icon input">
        <i className="user icon"></i>
        <Field
            name="email"
            component={renderInput}
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter your Email"
        />
    </div>
    <Fields names={fieldNames} component={this.renderEmailError} />
</div>
```

[image]
x

I was not able to get it working with the "standard" implementation using `Field` because my CSS simply does not allow for a div to be placed along with the input. I could not alter the CSS because of the way it places the icons on top of the input fields.

I experimented with moving the entire 'fieldset' into the `renderInput()` function, but I became equally stuck because of the onClick handler when you click the eyeball to expose the password (UX substitute for passwordConfirm field). I was not able to update the component state from outside the class, nor was I able to call the function properly from outside the class.

Additionally, I also learned that you cannot manipulate an input's *type* if it is *password* using `document.querySelector('input').type` because it is a security risk.

Comment: I'm leaving this answer "unanswered" for a while. I just re-visited this example today and after skilling up further, I now think the answer involves "lifting the state" into the first common ancestor, meaning, the container that this form is in.